# Mockito doAnswer()

Tags: java, spring, mockito, integration-testing, spring-rabbit

Can I somehow use `doAnswer()` when an exception is thrown?

I'm using this in my integration test to get method invocations and the test in configured the `@RabbitListenerTest`...

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyIT {

@Autowired
private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

@Autowired
private MyRabbitListener myRabbitListener;

@Autowired
private RabbitListenerTestHarness harness;

@Test
public void testListener() throws InterruptedException {
  MyRabbitListener myRabbitListener = this.harness.getSpy("event");
  assertNotNull(myRabbitListener);

  final String message = "Test Message";
  LatchCountDownAndCallRealMethodAnswer answer = new LatchCountDownAndCallRealMethodAnswer(1);
  doAnswer(answer).when(myRabbitListener).event(message);

  rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("exchange", "key", message);

  assertTrue(answer.getLatch().await(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
  verify(myRabbitListener).messageReceiver(message);
}

@Configuration
@RabbitListenerTest
public static class Config {
  @Bean
  public MyRabbitListener myRabbitListener(){
    return new MyRabbitListener();
  }
 }
}
```

It works ok but when I introduce an `Exception` being thrown, It doesn't i.e

This works

```
@RabbitListener(id = "event", queues = "queue-name")
  public void event(String message) {
    log.info("received message > " + message);
}
```

This doesn't

```
@RabbitListener(id = "event", queues = "queue-name")
  public void event(String message) {
    log.info("received message > " + message);
    throw new ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException("Invalid message, " + message);
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Yes, you can. Post a **complete** minimal example reproducing the issue. Womplete means: we must be able to copy and paste the code in our IDE, and run it without having to make modifications or write additional code.

Comment: edit coming up!

Comment: doAnswer/when exception is thrown ????? yyyyyyy

Comment: When an exception is thrown a message is re delivered.

Comment: But why would you mock bussiness logic of tested component.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LatchCountDownAndCallRealMethodAnswer` is very basic

```
@Override
public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
    invocation.callRealMethod();
    this.latch.countDown();
    return null;
}
```

You can copy it to a new class and change it to something like

```
private volatile Exception exeption;

@Override
public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
    try {
        invocation.callRealMethod();
    } 
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
        this.exception = e;
        throw e;
    }
    finally {
        this.latch.countDown();
    }
    return null;
}

public Exception getException() {
    return this.exception;
}
```

then

```
assertTrue(answer.getLatch().await(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
assertThat(answer.getException(), isInstanceOf(ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException.class));
```

Please open a github issue; the framework should support this out-of-the-box.